# How to include an image into a Select Option label, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am new to React and I am trying to create a drop-down with images in the labels and I am using a function to get the values from a map and build an id: label pair to show as options in the drop-down. where both id and label are of string type.

I am trying to retrieve the options like this:

```
const options = (): Select.Option[] => {
  return VALUES.map((color) => convertIdtoSelect(color));
};
```

where, VALUES is of type:

```
export const VALUES: ValueDef[] = [
 {
   id: 'blue'
   name: 'Blue Color'
 },
 {
   id: 'red'
   name: 'Red color'
 },
];
```

Here the method convertIdtoSelect looks like:

```
export function convertIdtoSelect(color: ValueDef): Select.Option {
 return {
  id: color.id,
  label: `${color.name}` // Insert an image in this label that I have in a directory, before the name.
 };
}
```

Please let me know how do I do this. I tried:

```
label: `<div><img src={/img/src/${color.id}.png} height="30px" width="30px"/> ${color.name} </div>`,
```

which doesn't work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: "Doesn't work." Can you describe specifically *what* doesn't work?

Comment: My drop-down label gets populated as: `<div><img src ={'/img/src/blue.png'} height="30px" width="30px" /> Red Color </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's React you can pass JSX directly into the object

```
export function convertIdtoSelect(color: ValueDef): Select.Option {
 return {
  id: color.id,
  label: <div><img src={`/img/src/${color.id}.png`} height="30px" width="30px">{color.name}</div> // Insert an image in this label that I have in a directory, before the name.
 };
}
```

And then just render it using `{item.label}` (assuming `item` is the variable returned from the function)

Comment: Without the "``" tags surrounding the `<div>` tag it is not accepting the value.